# syncing a Core Data XML store to disk

Tags: xml, cocoa, core-data

I'm using Core Data with an XML store in my OSX app. I've noticed a problem that sometimes when I kill the app in Xcode, some data created during the last session is lost after a restart.

I've used opensnoop to check file access, and I've noticed that the file on the disk isn't actually updated after a change, even though I call save: on the managed object context - it's only synced to disk when the app quits properly. If it's killed suddenly, it doesn't get to save the file at all.

I'll probably switch to SQLite store anyway, but I'm wondering - is thare any way at all to force syncing the XML store to disk immediately? I don't see any methods in any relevant classes that would do this, and the Core Data guide docs don't seem to mention this either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my bad - the problem was actually caused not by the store type, but by the way the managed object contexts were organized - the records were saved into a child store, but the file on the disk is only updated when the parent store is saved too. It seems an XML store is also synced to disk almost instantly if you only manage this properly.